# JQuery: Operations on output value, but still keeping it printing as user types

Tags: jquery, html, math, keyup

In my HTML I have this:

```
 <input type="text" name="earned" id="earned">  
 <p>You have: $<span id="amount"></span></p>
```

And in my Javascript file I have this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#earned').keyup(function(){
        var $earned = this;
        $earned = $earned/100;
        $('#amount').text($(earned).val()+ '.00');
    });
});
```

I wrote this code for a simple calculator. If I wanted to grab what the user was typing and change it as they typed, how would I go about this? How come just dividing it by 100 doesn't work? It just outputs the number being typed in.

Comment: Why not reduce that to just `$('#amount').text($(this).val()/100);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#earned').keyup(function(){
    var $earned = parseInt($(this).val(), 10)/100; // .val() here
    $('#amount').html($earned+ '.00'); // Variable here
});
```

The `this` refers to the DOM input field. So you need the jQuery object of that and the `.val()` of that input field. Parse that to an integer, because Strings can't be divided. And than set the output to the span.

Answer (score 0):

`var $earned = this;` is your problem. Use `var $earned = this.val();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do.

```
$(function(){
  $('#earned').change(function(){
    var num_val = $(this).val();
    if(num_val!="")
    {
        num_val = num_val/100
    }
    $('#amount').text(num_val+ '.00');
  });
});
```